# twilio not making calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am using ruby and rails to make  a call to number A that then uses TwiML to dial number B. I see in my twilio logs that it is calling number A and I get charged for it, but I never receive any of the calls. I have tried calling different numbers and never get anything at number A.  the TwiML gets executed though and number B always gets called. what am I doing wrong so that number A never gets called?

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
id = 5
call = client.account.calls.create({:from =>FROM , :to => phone, :url => "http://URL/connector?id=#{id}"})
```

the TwiML in a rails controller:

```
def connector
  id = params[:id] # call request id
  @call_request = CallRequest.find(id)
  phone = @call_request.to
  response =  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r| 
    r.Say "Connecting you"
    r.Dial phone
    r.Record :action => "http://URL/call_record?cr=#{id}", :method => 'get'
  end 
  render text: response.text
end
```

one question I have, does the voice request url for a number need to be set to match the url I set in the call request? here is what I have set: http://sharebucketapp.com/DgzNzkwMGRiODI4NTY5N

Comment: Is your connector action set up with a POST route?

Comment: yes it is,  the problem is very weird. disregarding the TwiML, the problem is that the call is not even connecting at all even though the twill is being read.

Comment: Is the number you are trying to dial on to in the correct format? (Phony might help here https://github.com/floere/phony)